# How to perform join operation between encrypted tables of a database (MySQL and Oracle)?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, security, encryption

I want to encrypt my tables such that union, intersection and join operations are still feasible.
Suppose I have two tables both encrypted and I wish to perform following operation:

```
Select *   
from table1, table2   
where table1.attr1 >= table2.attr2
```

My question is how should I perform encryption?
and once encrypted how to perform join/intersection/union between different tables?

Comment: You'd have to encrypt each field seperately, and use the same encryption method/key on both servers. Otherwise it'd be comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: What type of encryption are you talking about? Both databases have transparent encryption capabilities, meaning that you can use any and all SQL statements without worrying about the encryption... Are you talking about that? If not be much more specific about the encryption you want to do.

Comment: @Marc B: I'm wondering which encryption method will work with @Ravi example code

Comment: Whatever you end up using, it has to be the same on both databases. I'd suggest AES, since it's standard and well documented. THere's no point in using AES on mysql and (says) 3DES on oracle - you'll get different outputs and won't be able to compare without doing trans-cryption each time.